# Flicker with Core Graphics and Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I recently switched from Carbon 32bit to Cocoa 64bit.

When zooming in and out with ctrl-MouseWheel I get white flicker in my window. In addition, graphics performance is low.

In Carbon, I obtained my graphics context with

```
CGrafPtr port = GetWindowPort(window);
QDBeginCGContext(port, &contextRef);
```

For Cocoa, I use

```
CGContextRef myContext = (CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
```

in the `drawRect` method.

Additionally I set a timer with 25 fps:

```
runLoopTimerRef = CFRunLoopTimerCreate(...);
CFRunLoopAddTimer(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopTimerRef, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
```

for repeated drawing via `setNeedsDisplay:YES`. I need to redraw the entire content every time.

Nearly all drawing is made with CoreGraphics (CGContext... calls and so on).

Compared to Carbon, the Cocoa stuff is really slow (reactions to mouse clicks are delayed).

When I set

```
[self setOpaque:YES];
```

in my `drawRect` method, the flicker color becomes black instead of white.

There are no layers or backbuffers.

Any idea what might be wrong? Some setup/state calls missing in my `drawRect` method?

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the solution: I draw a lot of bitmaps. These bitmaps had to be scaled for retina displays during the drawRect call.

Providing high resolution bitmaps for retina displays solved the problem.